# How to use hooks in react-query onError handler?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

We are using `Next.js` with `react-query` everywhere. What we want to do is to have a **global query** setup that when a call to an endpoint fails because the access token expired, it refreshes the token and re-runs the query.

The error mode should be that the user gets redirected to login. We have come a long way with using `react-query's` built in `onError` and retry settings.

With a custom function we can refresh the token and then retry the original request again. However, after trying again, we would want to redirect the user to the login page. For this we need `useRouter` from `Next` which is a **hook**. `useQuery` in `react-query` is also a **hook**.

Is there a way to combine these two, so that we can use the router inside the `onError` of `QueryClient`? Or is this completely the wrong way to go about it?

What we are trying is something like this:

```js
export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      onError: () => router.push('/login'),
    }
  }
})
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you setup the query client inside of the app function using state as described in the hydration step of the docs? https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/ssr#using-hydration. If you can, then you should be able to use the router hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import your router instance directly then use it to configure the query client.

```js
import Router from 'next/router'
// ...

export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      onError: () => Router.push('/login'),
    }
  }
})
```

This is discussed here: [Using next/router outside of components](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17046)